# Regular expression: matching the same character repeatedly

Tags: regex

I was practicing regular expressions and attempted to write a regex which will detect 
"cay" and "cabby" and also "catty". I feel this is correct:

```
ca(([bt])\1*)?y
```

but on trying this on RegexBuddy, I see that it only matches "cay". Can anyone find the problem?

thanks, Mishal

Comment: Ignore Grabovsky.. his expression will also match caby.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must count parentheses correctly:

```
ca(([bt])\2)?y
```

would capture `cay`, `cabby`, `catty`.

The simpler:

```
ca(bb|tt)?y
```

would capture `cay`, `cabby`, `catty` explicitly.

---

PS: I thought quantifying back-references (as in `\2*`) was not possible, but in fact it is. If you want to match any amount of *only* `"t"` or *only* `"b"`, the following would be okay:

```
ca(([bt])\2*)?y
```

matches `cay`, `caby`, `cabby`, `cabbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbby`, `catttty`, etc. It can be simplified to the equivalent:

```
ca([bt])\1*y
```

because such a construct `(x*)?` is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick without backreferences:

```
ca(?:bb|tt)?y
```

Answer (score 1):

with a noncapturing group

```
ca(?:bb|tt)?y
```

or simpler without

```
ca(bb|tt)?y
```

Comment: This would catch BB, BT, TB and TT as well. Not just BB and TT.